# Add new Key to json by getting it from same json using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a json and I am writing the content as CSV file.In the json, the key 'latitude' is a list and it contains null or two keys('Time','Rate') and values. While writing as csv, I want to add new columns instead of 'latitude' column. Columns Like,

1. latitude_time -get value of Time inside the list/ null if no value
2. latitude_rate -get value of Rate inside the list/ null if no value

OR

if the new keys and values can be added in the JSON itself in replacement of Key 'latitude' - Then, the json can be written as CSV

```
import json, csv

x="""[
    {"longitude":"-73.689070","latitude":[]},
    {"longitude":"-73.689930","latitude":[{"Time":0,"Rate":"Hourly"}]}
]"""

rows = json.loads(x)
fieldnames = ['longitude', 'latitude']
with open('test.csv', 'wb+') as f:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    dict_writer.writerow(dict(zip(fieldnames, fieldnames)))
    dict_writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Load JSON in a variable. Get value data for "latitude" key. Delete the key. Add new keys to the variable with relevant data. Dump the variable to get new JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can iterate through rows and replace the latitude dict with required keys e.g.

```
import json, csv

x="""[
    {"longitude":"-73.689070","latitude":[]},
    {"longitude":"-73.689930","latitude":[{"Time":0,"Rate":"Hourly"}]}
]"""
rows = json.loads(x)
new_rows = []
for row in rows:
    latitude_time = None
    latitude_rate = None
    latitude = row['latitude']
    if latitude:
        latitude_time = latitude[0].get('Time', None)
        latitude_rate = latitude[0].get('Rate', None)
    row.pop('latitude')
    row.update({'latitude_time' : latitude_time,'latitude_rate':latitude_rate })
    row = {key:str(value) for key, value in row.items()}
    new_rows.append(row)
print new_rows
```

Comment: Thanks @Amit Nanaware!! But I get the output as unicode format.
[{'latitude_rate': None, 'latitude_time': None, u'longitude': u'-73.689070'}, {'latitude_rate': u'Hourly', 'latitude_time': 0, u'longitude': u'-73.689930'}]

Comment: `row = {key:str(value) for key, value in row.items()}` add this line before `new_row.append(row)`

Comment: Thanks @Amit Nanaware